# Wordpress Category image display

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am using a script found at http://wpdevsnippets.com/add-category-tag-taxonomy-picture/.  However, I cannot get the writer to answer a usage question, so here it is:

How do I use this script with a custom taxonomy on a page.php or archive.php template?

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wpds_admin_head');
add_action('edit_term', 'wpds_save_tax_pic');
add_action('create_term', 'wpds_save_tax_pic');
function wpds_admin_head() {
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
//$taxonomies = array('category'); // uncomment and specify particular taxonomies you want to add image feature.
if (is_array($taxonomies)) {
    foreach ($taxonomies as $z_taxonomy) {
        add_action($z_taxonomy . '_add_form_fields', 'wpds_tax_field');
        add_action($z_taxonomy . '_edit_form_fields', 'wpds_tax_field');
    }
}
}

// add image field in add form
function wpds_tax_field($taxonomy) {
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
if(empty($taxonomy)) {
    echo '<div class="form-field">
            <label for="wpds_tax_pic">Picture</label>
            <input type="text" name="wpds_tax_pic" id="wpds_tax_pic" value="" />
        </div>';
}
else{
    $wpds_tax_pic_url = get_option('wpds_tax_pic' . $taxonomy->term_id);
    echo '<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="wpds_tax_pic">Picture</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="wpds_tax_pic" id="wpds_tax_pic" value="' . $wpds_tax_pic_url . '" /><br />';
    if(!empty($wpds_tax_pic_url))
        echo '<img src="'.$wpds_tax_pic_url.'" style="max-width:200px;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 5px;box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ccc;margin-top: 10px;" >';
    echo '</td></tr>';        
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#wpds_tax_pic").click(function() {
                tb_show("", "media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true");
                return false;
            });
            window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
                jQuery("#wpds_tax_pic").val( jQuery("img",html).attr("src") );
                tb_remove();
            }
    });
</script>';
}

// save our taxonomy image while edit or save term
function wpds_save_tax_pic($term_id) {
if (isset($_POST['wpds_tax_pic']))
    update_option('wpds_tax_pic' . $term_id, $_POST['wpds_tax_pic']);
}

// output taxonomy image url for the given term_id (NULL by default)
function wpds_tax_pic_url($term_id = NULL) {
if ($term_id) 
    return get_option('wpds_tax_pic' . $term_id);
elseif (is_category())
    return get_option('wpds_tax_pic' . get_query_var('cat')) ;
elseif (is_tax()) {
    $current_term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
    return get_option('wpds_tax_pic' . $current_term->term_id);
}
}
```

And here is the function that is used to call this:

```
wpds_tax_pic_url();
```

or

```
wpds_tax_pic_url($category->cat_ID);
```

How do I use this script with a custom taxonomy on a page.php or archive.php template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On archive.php, you can use the wpds_tax_pic_url(); without any parameters it should display the URL of the attached image.

```
if(wpds_tax_pic_url()){
  echo '<img src="'.wpds_tax_pic_url().'" />';
}else{
  // other image or nothing.
}
```

On page.php or post.php, something following would work

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'custom_taxonomy');
foreach ($terms as $t) {
    if(wpds_tax_pic_url($t->term_id))
        echo '<img src="'.wpds_tax_pic_url($t->term_id).'" />';
}
```